# How to determine the type of the platform in Dialogflow (API.AI)

Tags: dialogflow-es

How do to identify from which platform the message came?

I want to support different platforms like Telegram and Facebook Messenger, When my webhook receive a message, I want to reply according to the platform the message came form.

For example, if the message came from Telegram I want to return a text message but if the message came from messenger I want to return a card.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a property `source` in `originalRequest` object, see fulfillment [docs here](https://api.ai/docs/fulfillment#request).

```
{
"lang": "en", 
"status": {
    "errorType": "success", 
    "code": 200
}, 
"timestamp": "2017-02-09T16:06:01.908Z", 
"sessionId": "1486656220806", 
"result": {
    "parameters": {
        "city": "Rome", 
        "name": "Ana"
    }, 
    "contexts": [], 
    "resolvedQuery": "my name is Ana and I live in Rome", 
    "source": "agent", 
    "score": 1.0, 
    "speech": "", 
    "fulfillment": {
        "messages": [
            {
                "speech": "Hi Ana! Nice to meet you!", 
                "type": 0
            }
        ], 
        "speech": "Hi Ana! Nice to meet you!"
    }, 
    "actionIncomplete": false, 
    "action": "greetings", 
    "metadata": {
        "intentId": "9f41ef7c-82fa-42a7-9a30-49a93e2c14d0", 
        "webhookForSlotFillingUsed": "false", 
        "intentName": "greetings", 
        "webhookUsed": "true"
    }
}, 
"id": "ab30d214-f4bb-4cdd-ae36-31caac7a6693", 
"originalRequest": {
    "source": "google", 
    "data": {
        "inputs": [
            {
                "raw_inputs": [
                    {
                        "query": "my name is Ana and I live in Rome", 
                        "input_type": 2
                    }
                ], 
                "intent": "assistant.intent.action.TEXT", 
                "arguments": [
                    {
                        "text_value": "my name is Ana and I live in Rome", 
                        "raw_text": "my name is Ana and I live in Rome", 
                        "name": "text"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ], 
        "user": {
            "user_id": "PuQndWs1OMjUYwVJMYqwJv0/KT8satJHAUQGiGPDQ7A="
        }, 
        "conversation": {
            "conversation_id": "1486656220806", 
            "type": 2, 
            "conversation_token": "[]"
        }
    }
} }
```

Comment: Is this JSON object the same for every platform?

Comment: The structure is the same but the properties will vary depending of the platform. Happy coding.